# Find all uncompressed tables in Teradata

Tags: sql, database, compression, teradata

Is there a way to find all the uncompressed tables in teradata ?

So far I am doing it manually by using

```
SHOW TABLE <TABLE_NAME>
```

and checking if a column has `COMPRESS` keyword. This gets a lot tedious if I have 100s of tables.

Is there a column or table where I can query for such tables something like I can check for Macro -

```
SELECT * FROM dbc.tables WHERE tablekind='M' AND databasename='database'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all compressed columns:

```
select * from dbc.ColumnsV 
where CompressValueList is not null
```

To get tables without any compress:

```
SELECT * FROM dbc.TablesV
WHERE TableKind IN ('T', 'O') -- both PI and NoPI tables
AND (DatabaseName, TableName) NOT IN 
 (
   SELECT DatabaseName, TableName 
   FROM dbc.columnsv
   WHERE CompressValueList IS NOT NULL
 )
```

Comment: Is there a diffrence between `dbc.TablesV` and `dbc.Tables` ?

Comment: @PirateX: Of course, all non-V views are legacy since TD12 and should not be used anymore. When you're on TD14.10+ and use object names longer than 30 characters `dbc.Tables` will truncate them.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, compression is more a "column thing" rather than a "table thing", so you'd better check in the column metadata:

That's a possible query (to be improved):

```
  select  t.tablename, sum(case when compressvaluelist is null then 0 else 1 end) compressed_cols, count(*) cols  
    from dbc.ColumnsV c join dbc.TablesV t on (c.tablename=t.tablename and c.databasename=t.databasename) 
   where t.databasename='<databasename>'
     and t.tablekind in ('T','O')
   group by 1    
  having compressed_cols=0
```

Comment: This will return all Macros/SPs/Views, etc., you need to join to dbc.TablesV to get the TableKind 'T'.

Comment: @dnoeth Right, thanks.. I've also added tablekind 'O' for nopi tables.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about those, too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dbc table columns for that . Compressible = 'C' will give you those values.

```
select databasename,tablename,columnname,compressible
from dbc.columns
where compressible in ('A','C')
```

by the way in y our query why you are choosing tablekind='M', it will not return details of table but will return detail of macro.

Comment: You should switch to `where compressible in ('A','C')`, otherwise you omit columns with Algorithmic compression.